# What unvisible process consumes almoust all RAM?

Tags: fedora, process, memory, ram, stability

I am using Fedora but had this issue also with other distros for a long time and never found a solution.

So while using my computer, mostly only browsing with Brave and coding with VStudio, memory usage slowly increases. After few hours linux starts choking so I shut down all programs too free up some memory and this is what I see:

[image: Ram almoust full]

Could you tell me what process is eating that almost 10GB? And how to kill it?

(Please ignore qemu, this uses about 6GB it is supposed to be).

Thank you all!

Comment: Where do you get the idea that a process is consuming 10GB? Did you check the output of `free`?

Comment: Well I had 16GB eaten by something while qemu ate 6GB of ram, so I was looking for the process that ate rest.. I think the answer below solved my problem.

Comment: Like I said, look at the output of `free`.

Comment: and/or show `cat /proc/meminfo` (`free` eseentially takes its data from the same source)

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't find a process consuming RAM except from qemu it could be disk caching, you can check the following link for more informaton https://www.linuxatemyram.com/